# Generate certificate without Basic constraints

Tags: openssl, client-certificate

A business partner requires a client certificate, to be able to access some of their API's.

I generated a cert with OpenSSL, using the command:

`openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout mykey.pem -out mycert.pem -sha256 -days 365`

The business partner says that the cert contains something in the "Basic constraints" section of the certificate, and that the certificate needs to be completely without Basic constraints. They also showed me a screenshot of a valid certificate, that did not have any Basic constraints.

I tried adding the parameter `-addext "basicConstraints=CA:FALSE,pathlen:0"`, but this generated a cert with two of these sections, which looks like it may not be valid:

[image: Screenshot of the certificate with two Basic Constraints sections.]

How can I generate a client certificate without the Basic constraints section?

Comment: Do you have/know where you have a openssl.cnf configuration file? Check there if you can remove/comment out the basicConstraints line under ext, and the generate the cert

Comment: @YisroelTech That was in fact the issue, thank you for pointing me in that direction. I used `openssl version -d` to get the location of the configuration file, and there I saw a lot of lines about basic constraints. I commented them out, ran my command again, and generated a cert without basic constraints. 

If you post it as an answer, I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **basicConstraints** [certificate extension](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man5/x509v3_config.html) isn't required, and is likely loaded from your `openssl` that has it there with settings.

- Use `openssl version -d` to get the location of your openssl files
- In that directory find and edit the **openssl.cnf** configuration file
- Comment out the ***basicConstraints*** lines (there might be several depending on the type of cert being generated), and save the file
- Regenerate the cert